# fnReloadAjax is not function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using Datatables, and the fnReloadAjax plugin (see below), I am trying to reload the table's data from a server-side script aftrer submit dialog form using the following code:

```js
submitHandler: function(form){
  jQueryNew(form).ajaxSubmit({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/sdm/surattugas/addagendanarasumber',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSubmit: function(data){
      jQueryNew("#dialog_add_agenda").dialog("close");
    },
    success: function(data){
      jQueryNew(dialog_add_agenda).dialog("close");
      jQueryNew(dialog_daftar_agenda).find('.tabel_agenda_message').removeClass('error').removeClass('success').removeClass('info').removeClass('warning').css("display", 'none').addClass('da-message').addClass(data.typeAlert).text(data.pesan).animate({opacity: 100}, function() {
        jQueryNew(this).slideDown('normal', function() {
          jQueryNew(this).css("display", 'block');
        });
      });

      if (data.typeAlert == 'success'){
        tabel_agenda.fnReloadAjax();                                                             }
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

```js
jQueryNew.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnReloadAjax = function ( oSettings, sNewSource, fnCallback, bStandingRedraw )
    {
        if ( typeof sNewSource != 'undefined' && sNewSource != null )
        {
            oSettings.sAjaxSource = sNewSource;
        }
        this.oApi._fnProcessingDisplay( oSettings, true );
        var that = this;
        var iStart = oSettings._iDisplayStart;
        var aData = [];
    
        this.oApi._fnServerParams( oSettings, aData );
    
        oSettings.fnServerData( oSettings.sAjaxSource, aData, function(json) {
            /* Clear the old information from the table */
            that.oApi._fnClearTable( oSettings );
    
            /* Got the data - add it to the table */
            var aData =  (oSettings.sAjaxDataProp !== "") ?
                that.oApi._fnGetObjectDataFn( oSettings.sAjaxDataProp )( json ) : json;
    
            for ( var i=0 ; i<aData.length ; i++ )
            {
                that.oApi._fnAddData( oSettings, aData[i] );
            }
    
            oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();
            that.fnDraw();
    
            if ( typeof bStandingRedraw != 'undefined' && bStandingRedraw === true )
            {
                oSettings._iDisplayStart = iStart;
                that.fnDraw( false );
            }
    
            that.oApi._fnProcessingDisplay( oSettings, false );
    
            /* Callback user function - for event handlers etc */
            if ( typeof fnCallback == 'function' && fnCallback != null )
            {
                fnCallback( oSettings );
            }
        }, oSettings );
    }
```

But I still get the this.oApi._fnServerParams is not a function. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just use this.oApi.ajax.reload( null, false );

Answer (score -1):

The Datatables api says fnReloadAjax is deprecated.
https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnReloadAjax

Instead it suggests to use this:
https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: fnReloadAjax was used on another menu and its work, its mean its not deprecated. its something wrong with my code. im using fnStandingRedraw working fine.. but why using fnReloadAjax got this?

Comment: Yes, in the current release the function is still there, but it will be removed in one of the future releases. So I'm not sure why your code isn't working. But have your tried replacing the call tabel_agenda.fnReloadAjax() with tabel_agenda.ajax.reload(); to see if it works with the new api?

Comment: got this : TypeError: tabel_agenda.ajax is undefined .  

tabel_agenda.ajax.reload(); my data table version is 1.10, jQuery 1.8

Comment: This should fix the error: tabel_agenda.api().ajax.reload()